postgresql-16.3-1-windows-x64 installation error
enter image description here
the error message is "There has been an error.
Error running C:\WINDOWS\System32\icacls"C:\Windows\Temp/postgresql_installer_98a2857089" T/Q/grant "KAIRUUU:(OI)(CI)F":C:\Windows\Temp/postgresql_installer_98a2857089*: Access is denied."
I've tried a lot of solutions online can't remember some of them, and i'm stuck in this problem

Hi @khyle, I am also facing same issue. Did you get any solution?

unfortunately, i wasn't able to resolve this issue. I've tried a lot of options and solution online and still i encounter this kind of issue

At last, I have formatted laptop and it's working fine. Didn't get exact issue.
